# Error creating socket in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, network-programming

I am very new to socket or network programing . I am just trying to create a socket but python is giving me traceback.
I am using python 2.7 on Ubuntu 12

my code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'OK'
```

traceback is :

```
    Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 66, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, urllib, re, pwd, grp, os
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/home/ans/Desktop/python_p/socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/home/ans/Desktop/python_p/socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AF_INET'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You named your program file `socket.py`, so this file is imported, instead of the standard library module. Rename your file, remove any `socket.pyc` and try again.